# MVC 3 Fall-through routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Sorry for asking a rather n00b question, I am rather new to ASP.NET MVC.
My problem is as follows:

I want my site to handle a URL in the following way:

```
www.mysite.com/homepage/name
```

I want the above link to go to that user's profile. For simplicity the controller will be the Homepage controller with the Test action.

Meaning that the global.asax routing will be:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "test",
            "homepage/{name}",
            new { controller = "Homepage", action = "Test" }
            );
```

Up until now the code works great (I have tested it and it routes ok).

But now my other functionality which I want is to enable:

```
www.mysite.com/homepage/action/id
```

To work as well.

The routing for this will be:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "homepage/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Homepage", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The problem is what happens when a user wants to omit the {id} for an action, the routing table detects that the action name is actually the {name} parameter.

Is there any way to first CHECK if an action exists. And only if it doesn't, then use it as a parameter for a different route.

Makes sense? if not I'll add some more details.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

So I've managed to solve this using the constraints regex
I placed a regex defining a all the actions in my controller:

```
routes.MapRoute(
           "homepage",
           "homepage/{action}/{id}",
           new { controller = "Homepage", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
           new { action = "(action1|action2|action3)" }
           );
```

And then the next rule:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "feed",
            "homepage/{id}",
            new { controller = "Homepage", action = "Test"}
            );
```

I works ok, only it's hard to scale upon this. You need to remember to place every new action on the controller inside the string here. It's a huge opening for debug nightmares.

Thank you !

Comment: What happens if a user creates an account called Index, or whatever your action name is?

Comment: I'm guessing that it all needs to be synchronized with DB management. It is a good question. The way we do it is generate those slugs ourselves so we hold the right to reserve some strings.

Comment: I guess my point is that it's really better to design things so such confusions cannot occur, by using a different path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the `Default` route first, and also restrict its allowed values

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "homepage/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Homepage", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new {action = @"Index|Delete|Add"}
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            "test",
            "homepage/{name}",
            new { controller = "Homepage", action = "Test" }
            );
```

This way the first route will only be used if the action value matches one provided in the constraint, otherwise it will move to the next rule.

You will also have to make sure when you create user profiles, that no name should match one of your supported actions for the `default` route.

Comment: Thank you. As I've edited the post, it works. but it's hard to scale. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Omer, if you want to ***on-the-fly*** check if the action exists then look at this answer from frenky on [How to make sure controller and action exists before doing redirect, asp.net mvc3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7036978/128165)

Comment: It looks good. Is there any chance that it will slow down my routing? is there an efficiency loss here?

Comment: @omer, i wouldn't know.. perhaps  you could comment on his answer and ask him about it.. (*or perhaps a new question on SO about it*)

Answer (score 1):

Since ASP.NET MVC selects the first route from the `RouteTable` that matches the current request, you should be able to fix this problem by changing the order of the routes in the Global.asax.

First this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "homepage/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Homepage", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and then this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "test",
            "homepage/{name}",
            new { controller = "Homepage", action = "Test" }
            );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this way the second route will never be reached.. You should use a constraint on the `action` to only allow a specific list of `actions`

Comment: It doesn't help. It still tries to parse the 'id' field as an action and returns a 404 not found.