# Redirect to url in ASP MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

I have an action result method that inside is doing a Redirect(url). My question is how can I check that the url is valid before I do the redirect ?

```
public ActionResult RedirectUser()
{
    var url = "/Cars/Model/1"; //this is the url

    // now i should check if the redirect return a 200 code (the url is valid) and if is valid I should redirect to that url, else i should redirect to "/Home/Index"

    if(this.Redirect(url))
    {
       return this.Redirect(url);
    }
    else
    {
       return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Can anyone help me with an example ? I search on google but I couldn't find anything to help me. Thanks

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033428/how-to-make-sure-controller-and-action-exists-before-doing-redirect-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Yes, I checked that link. It's not what I need because the method Redirect() could have as paramater the link in this form ("/Home/Car/1"). Firstly I thought that I could do a ping to that url but I don't have the host.

Comment: if your link is not complete for example "/Home/Car/1" then you can safely append your application url base address

Comment: Why do you need to check if the URL works? Is it always going to be an internal (relative) URL or it could be external?

One easy way to do this would be using HttpClient to send a get request and check the response status.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
public ActionResult RedirectUser()
{
    var url = "/Cars/Model/1"; //this is the url

     var controller = RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
 var action = RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

    if(controller=="car"&& action=="Model")
    {
       return this.Redirect(url);
    }
    else
    {
       return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() is returning the current controller and the same for action. I dont need to check if my url contains the current controller because I can redirect the user to another location (in another controller). Let's say I'm in account controller in logIn action result, what you wrote there is return "account" and "logIn".

Comment: want you check before redirect page?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the url that you're trying to redirect to is under your MVC app's control, you can use the url helper Url.Action to guarantee that it is valid.

```
Url.Action("Model","Cars", new {id=1});
//should yield "Cars/Model/1 if your routing is configured to have id to be optional as below:
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Cars", action = "Model", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Warning: Your sample code may not reflect your prod code but url should not be hard-coded in the way your have.  This will blow up when "Cars" is not at the root of app in your deployment environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpClient to send a get request like so:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("Cars/Model/1");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
         // redirect here
    }
}
```